# Excel export works locally, fields become hidden when running on server

Tags: excel, apache-poi, smartgwt

OK, so i have a SmartGWT web application, where i have some reports running in list grids.

I export to excel using the Smartgwt built-in export as per the examples using the listgrid.exportclientdata();

Here's the issue:

-When running locally, all works fine and i can open the XLSX file and see all data.

-When running from the server, the columns containing data become hidden! If i manually do the "unhide" thing from within Excel, i can see the columns...

My local environment is Mac OSX, Mountain Lion(also tried earlier), running Sun's Java.
The prod server is Debian running OpenJDK.

Not sure if that would have something to do with it, and i am at a loss as to how i go about solving it... Running my webapp on Tomcat6 in both environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others, searching the stackoverflow void for answers to riddles in the dark:

This was caused by certain fonts not being available in OpenJDK, without any errors being logged anywhere...

I switched to Sun's JDK on my Debian as well, and the Excel files now open and display properly.

Answer (score 1):

This an also happen when facing [this POI Bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55644) that seems to be related to a [Java Bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8013716).

If it's the case changing the Font to something other than Calibri or using jre above 7u21 should fix the issue.
You can also mitigitate the issue and avoid the columns from being totally collapsed by using a code like this

    `sheet.autoSizeColumn(x);
    if (sheet.getColumnWidth(x) == 0) {
      // autosize failed use MIN_WIDTH
      sheet.setColumnWidth(x, MIN_WIDTH);
    }`